# Limit of $f(x,y) = (\sin(x) - \sin(y) )/ (\tan(x) - \tan(y))$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm asked to check if there exists $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ for the following function:
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x) - \sin(y)}{\tan(x) - \tan(y)} & \text{ if } \tan x \neq \tan y\\
\cos^{3} (x) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I have a guess that the limit exists and is equal to $1$, but I'm unable both to prove it or deny it.

The most natural manipulation (expanding $\tan$'s in the denominator and applying trigonometric identities) gives me for $\tan x \neq \tan y$ that $f(x,y) = \cos x \cos y(\sin(x) - \sin(y))/\sin(x-y)$, which doesn't help much. Any ideas or a good counterexample for my conjecture?

Comment: Try $\frac{x-y}{\tan(x)-\tan(y)} \cdot \frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,y)=\frac{2\cos{\frac{x+y}{2}}\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}\cos{x}\cos{y}}{\sin{(x-y)}}$, when we use the formula $\sin{x}-\sin{y}=2\cos{\frac{x+y}{2}}\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}$. Now we need to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}}{\sin{(x-y)}}$, since all other factors tend do $1$. Now $t=x-y$ and $t\to 0$ should give you the wanted result.

Comment: You can do a further simplification: $\sin(x-y)=2\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}$, so one gets only $(\cos\frac{x-y}{2})^{-1}$, which is even easier.

Comment: Great, I never remember of such trigonometric identities! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can help you:

- Since $\sin t\sim t $ as $t \to 0$ and $\tan t  \to \sin t $ as $ t\to 0$ (infinitesimals), then
- Your limit can be rewritten as follows:

$$L = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x-y}{x-y} = 1$$

- And the limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ and in $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: \ \tan{x} \neq \tan{y} \}$ and everywhere else meet.

I hope this approach is correct and may be useful to you.

Cheers!